# Client terminating on execution (pthread)

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

I have a socket programming problem. I am running the server and then it waits for the client. Once I run the client though, nothing happens, it just terminates and brings back the prompt. Basically it compiles alright but it doesn't run at all. It terminates as soon as I run it. This only happens when I use threads in the client code.

This is the code I'm using:

```
if(pthread_create(&threadID[i++], NULL, (void *)dostuff, (void *)(intptr_t)sock) != 0)  
        {
        perror("Thread create error");
        }
```

On the other hand, if I type in simply

```
dostuff(sock);
```

The client program does execute. I need threading because I need to implement I/O multiplexing. Could you tell me how to stop the client from terminating when I use threads?

Comment: @Douglas Please tell me how to do that. I'm really losing my mind! My deadline is in a few hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wait for the thread to finish before exiting the program, for example using [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_join.html)

```
// do this before returning from main
pthread_join(threadID[i], NULL);
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did. I put it right after the pthread_create loop. It did nothing. Should that be i++ or i?

Comment: I added this after the pthread_create

int res;
 res = pthread_join(threadID[i], NULL);
 printf("pthread joined?\n");
 if(res != 0) { 
  perror("Thread join failed");
  }

And now the first line of my client program prints, but then I get

Thread join failed: Success

Comment: Before returning from main? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I was oversimplifying with using just `[i]`. If you're creating an array of threadIds, you'll have to iterate over them (eg with a for loop) and wait for each in turn.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a [main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B) somewhere in your call stack. When you return from that, normally your process finishes.

Comment: No wait.. the program is running, but it still prints "Thread join failed: Success" at the prompt. This is the code I put in, what's wrong with it?

for(i=0; i<50; i++){
 if(pthread_join(threadID[i], NULL) != 0){ 
  perror("Thread join failed");
  }

Comment: That does sound like a contradictory error message, I'm not familiar with it. Are all the thread ids valid?

Comment: Well I wouldn't know how to find out if they weren't? For now, to get rid of the message, I'm just doing pthread_join without checking to see if it is successful. I know it's not right, but I will try to check it out later when I get the time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1825770 you should accept the answer if it helped you and/or vote up.